# Do all the Monk's damage boosting abilities stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I play as a Monk, and I have two pocket Wizards to kill things for me. Or put another way, my two Wizard friends have a pocket Monk, to keep mobs away from them and apply juicy damage debuffs.

Anyway, we were wondering, do all the Monk's damage-boosting debuffs stack? Specifically:

- [Crippling Wave with Breaking Wave](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/crippling-wave): +10% damage to mobs I hit
- [Inner Sanctuary with Forbidden Palace](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/inner-sanctuary): +30% damage to mobs in the sanctuary
- [Mantra of Conviction with Overawe](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/mantra-of-conviction): +16% damage to mobs around me

Do all these abilities work together, so that mobs could be taking an extra 56% damage?

Comment: As someone who played a Monk primarily and how swapped to Crusader this interests me as it might allow me to get into solo'ing Torment I like I do on my Crusader

Comment: yes it stacks, there's a nice damage spreadsheet that breaks down exactly how it stacks, but I don't have access to it at work right now.

Comment: Things in Diablo tend to stack as you hope they do.

Comment: Don't forget Exploding Palm's The Flesh is Weak: +20% to mobs marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, the answer to your question is provided by Mother Blizzard itself (just look at the "advanced" tootip on each ability), some other times, they need a little bit of testing.

- Crippling Wave - Breaking Wave (**YES**):
  Enemies hit by Crippling Wave take 10% additional damage **from all attacks** for 3 seconds.
- Inner Sanctuary - Forbidden Palace (**YES**):
  I play as a Monk since Diablo 3 was out, until now. I can confirm that the damage boost is significant, as reported by my fellow players.
- Mantra of Conviction - Overawe (**YES**)
  Same as point 2. The Mantra makes the monk invaluable for a party, due to its 16% to 20% damage boost!

So the answer is yes, if your enemies are hit by your crippling wave **AND** within your sanctuary **AND** within the AOE of your Mantra take 56% up to 60% damage (if you also activate the active ability of the Mantra).

Hope this helps!